# Multi Robots AMCL does not combine map and scan frames

Tags: amcl, ros-noetic

[image]
[image]

robot1/scan and robot1/map topics are working fine but some errors occurs

rqt

```
Warning: TF_OLD_DATA ignoring data from the past (Possible reasons are listed at http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Errors%20explained) for frame robot1/wheel_left_link (parent robot1/base_link) at time 381,579000 according to authority /robot1/robot_state_publisher
```

Gazebo warns

```
[ WARN] [1703782676.842833371, 1747.415000000]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_link to map to become available before running costmap, tf error: canTransform: target_frame map does not exist. canTransform: source_frame base_link does not exist.. canTransform returned after 0.1 timeout was 0.1.
[ WARN] [1703782677.956853274, 1748.528000000]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_link to map to become available before running costmap, tf error: canTransform: target_frame map does not exist. canTransform: source_frame base_link does not exist.. canTransform returned after 0.1 timeout was 0.1.
[ WARN] [1703782681.854312177, 1752.417000000]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_link to map to become available before running costmap, tf error: canTransform: target_frame map does not exist. canTransform: source_frame base_link does not exist.. canTransform returned after 0.1 timeout was 0.1.
[ WARN] [1703782682.976745664, 1753.531000000]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_link to map to become available before running costmap, tf error: canTransform: target_frame map does not exist. canTransform: source_frame base_link does not exist.. canTransform returned after 0.1 timeout was 0.1.
[ WARN] [1703782682.997570287, 1753.552000000]: No laser scan received (and thus no pose updates have been published) for 1753.552000 seconds.  Verify that data is being published on the /robot1/scan topic.
[ WARN] [1703782682.997993480, 1753.552000000]: No laser scan received (and thus no pose updates have been published) for 1753.552000 seconds.  Verify that data is being published on the /robot2/scan topic
```